# set label alpha and text hasn't effect after the second execution

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

i use this code after a database query:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (self.downlaodLabel) {
        NSLog(@"label is not nill");
        NSLog(@"text %@",self.downlaodLabel.text);
    }
    self.downlaodLabel.hidden = NO;
    [self.downlaodLabel setAlpha:1];
    [self.downlaodLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"on the map there are %lu pictures",(unsigned long)[self.mapView.annotations count]]];
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:5.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         [self.downlaodLabel setAlpha:0];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL fin){
                         if (fin) {
                         }
                     }];
});
```

the first time i call this code, everything works fine,infact the label correctly appear and disappear on the screen but the second time the code doesn't work, nothing appear on the screen. i can't understand whats wrong and why the first time all works fine.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you remove UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState option and use 0 value instead, everything will work as expected.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:0
                     animations:^{
                         [self.downlaodLabel setAlpha:0];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL fin){
                         if (fin) {
                         }
                     }];
```

Comment: 0 does nothing, it means that alpha animation should start from initial value instead of current value. You are trying to set alpha to 1 and then to 0 (with animation) in the same main thread run loop, so setAlpha:1 does nothing, only setAlpha:0 is taken into account.